# Google Drive - Authenticating with JSONClient using Node

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have succesfully authenticated using OAuth2 and now have an auth token.

Loading this token returns me a `JSONClient`:

```
const authClient = google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
```

Now trying to use this `JSONClient` gives me type errors:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: authClient });
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'JSONClient' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth<JSONClient> | OAuth2Client | undefined'.
      Type 'ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth<JSONClient> | OAuth2Client | undefined'.
```

The code runs fine, but VS code is giving me type errors, and it's bugging me!

What is the correct way to get a Drive (or Docs etc, it's all the same) client from a saved token?

And unbelievably AI has not solved all my problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly assert the type of authClient as OAuth2Client. TypeScript might not be able to infer the correct type in some cases.

const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: authClient as OAuth2Client });

This tells TypeScript that you know the type of authClient is OAuth2Client. While it might not eliminate the error in the editor, it should resolve the issue at runtime.